# Prime ideals in commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ (we take $R$ not to be a field for this post). Must $R$ contain at least one prime ideal that is not maximal?

The question is equivalent to the following: For a ring $R$ (commutative with 1) is there necessarily a integral domain $S$ which is not a field such that
there is a surjective ring homomorphism $R \twoheadrightarrow S$?

I feel that it's not true. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about a field $R$? Or, let $R$ be Artinian.

Comment: This answers my question! Thanks.

Comment: Note also that the Krull dimension is a measure of the lengths of chains of prime ideals, and any zero-dimensional ring has this property.

Comment: @user1 Please don't clutter the comments with answers: clutter the answers with your answers, please :)

Comment: @rschwieb I will keep that in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your intuition suggests, the answer is no. Any commutative ring with the property that all prime ideals are maximal necessarily has [Krull dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) zero, and conversely.

In fact, any commutative Artinian ring will do, since any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ contains a product of maximal ideals. This implies $\mathfrak p$ is itself a maximal ideal.

Comment: Boolean rings, products of fields ... there are lots of zero-dimensional rings.

Comment: I have not seen this notion of Krull dimension in my undergrad algebra courses. Both your comment and the answer were very informative.